# Is the try-catch-finally block synchronous in node.js?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, try-catch, child-process

I have some code runing in a **child process** in a node program like so:

```
try{
    var data = fs.readFileSync(urlPath, {"encoding":"utf8"});
} catch (err) {
    console.log("Error reading url file...");
    throw err;
} finally {
    console.log("File read!");
    var array = data.split("\n");

    console.log("Found " + array.length + " urls");
```

This code is called from another node program, that needs to **wait until all the operations in this file are done**.  Unfortunately, the child process is exiting with code 0 before any of the code under the `finally` block is executed.

This is leading me to believe even the `try-catch-finally` is asynchronous.  Is that correct?

Comment: That really wouldn't make sense.

Comment: Maybe I should open a new question, I just added some logging statements elsewhere and it appears the child process is exiting without even running those.

Comment: @MattBall please refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572834/child-process-in-node-js-mysteriously-exiting-between-lines-of-synchronous-code

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your question is confusingly worded.

The entire Javascript *language* is fully synchronous; all language constructs, including `catch` and `finally` blocks, will execute synchronously before running the next line of code.

However, they are not aware of any asynchronous operations that may have begun, and will not wait for them to finish.

Comment: Please refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17572834/child-process-in-node-js-mysteriously-exiting-between-lines-of-synchronous-code

Answer (score 1):

There are some ways to overcome this:

1) https://github.com/CrabDude/trycatch

See also
http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html

Comment: `domain` is deprecared!